# TimeZone for API range

Tags: apex, datetime

`Date.today()` returns the datetime for the current users timezone (ref: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm).
How do I make it return a date information in `UTC` format?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just the date format (i.e. MM/dd/yy vs dd/MM/yy) or the timezone?

Comment: @techtrekker timezone.  UTC is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
System.debug(Datetime.now().dateGMT());
```

which would return the [Date in the GMT Timezone](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)